# Is questioning a warning on Meta a Bannable offense

Tags: support

Are there any guidelines whether Meta questions should lead to banning? In this situation, a user (me) posted on Meta to question a warning received, which the user disagreed with. There was no vandalism, no spamming, no insulting, no harassment, nothing typically ban worthy. What reasons would normally justify a ban for meta posting asking for clarification?

Comment: Can you link to it? Without knowing how you worded your "question", we can't really say. If you were a dick about it, sure, it can get you banned. If you were polite and clear and making an honest attempt to understand, I would think that should be acceptable.

Comment: @Catija I am asking this in an objective manner, but see dom's comment at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260925/method-or-process-to-contest-wrongful-ban-by-mod?noredirect=1#comment850775_260925 for the link.

Comment: @Catija http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7056/limits-on-close-votes

Answer (score 26):

[From the thread referenced above](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7056/limits-on-close-votes/7057#7057):

> you appear to be flagging questions for closure in order to make some sort of point after having had your own question declined by the community.

There's a tendency to treat social systems as sort of a clockwork pinball game: put in your coin, get 3 plays to use however you wish as long as you bump the table *just* softly enough to [avoid triggering the tilt sensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinball#Nudging).

It's naive. This isn't a pinball game. Close flags are for helping your peers identify questions that have problems they need to address, and meta discussions are for working *with* your peers to answer questions or resolve disputes. **If you're clearly not using them for these purposes, then your privilege to do so will be revoked.**

Moderators are not clockwork; they are elected and *expected* to use their judgement to settle problems. If they notice you repeatedly nudging the table, you won't get to play anymore.

Comment: As I explained, and justified each of the questions that I VTC, because they were bad questions that went against policy. Most of those were VTC by others for the same reason. None were spit votes where the reason to close wasn't valid. See the revision: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/revisions/7057/3. I was not spamming random questions with invalid VTC flags.

Comment: @cde like Shog said, stop trying to nudge the table on this issue. It's only going to end up worse if you keep doing it.

Comment: I'm not the one you have to convince here. And it appears you've wasted your opportunity to respond to the moderator you *should* have been trying to convince.

Comment: The mod blindly left even the most egregious of the bad questions open simply because I had VTC, instead of reviewing them to see if the questions were wrongly VTC. You can't convince someone that won't even attempt to be objective.

Comment: And I had stopped VTC well before the warning. Simply defending my actions should not be reason to ban an hour later.

Comment: I've found that lamenting others' actions is rarely worth the time; they will do as they think they ought with or without my approval. My own actions, however, I have some small say in and should therefore reflect on. I highly recommend this.

Comment: @cde - Your comment before your spree belies what you are saying now.  "cde: "**Time to mark downvote *a literal ton of questions* for "lists"**". [emphasis mine] .  The fact that you deleted this comment after you caught everyone's attention is even more damning.

Answer (score 9):

[This is the meta post you referred to](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7056/limits-on-close-votes) and it's pretty easy that there's much more going on then you state.

The warning was for casting many questionable vote to closes in a short period of time. Asking about it for clarity was fine, but you also have to take into account how you asked it and your response when you got answers. This was your completed original post:

> What is the limit on close votes. What reasons would someone be
>   limited or threatened with suspension for voting to close on valid
>   close reasons.

A little bit to the point, but valid. Once you got answer though, you vigirously tried to defend yourself much beyond clarity even trying to [edit someone else's answer to explain yourself](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/7057/revisions) and in your post trying to cherry pick comments in the chat to fule your point.

Asking for clarity is one thing, but trying to prove everyone you're right and they are wrong *is not clairty* and it's that not asking for clarity that got you banned.

Comment: Yes, I edited an answer with a large list to explain, and made it clear it was my edit, not op's original, and commented as such to make it even more clear. *The link you use though is to my own question which I edited with proof that multiple people believed many of those questions were objectively bad and should be closed.*

Comment: @cde since when is it _ever_ ok to edit someone else's post to prove _your_ point?

Comment: @Catija he means this post http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/revisions/7057/3 which the mod edited in a list of the questions I VTC. I edited my reasons for each of those questions.

Comment: @cde That behavior is **never** OK. The main reason someone should edit someone else's question or answer is if there's an error of some sort or something needs to be removed for acceptability reasons (cussing, bad links, rude statements, off-topic content etc). Editing to respond to accusations is not an acceptable action and it was correct for them to roll it back.

Comment: @Catija I have no problem with a roll back. I thought it cleaner to respond that way, but I could always copy it into its own answer to respond. That mod didn't even bother to review those questions to see if they were valid flags or not, thats the issue.

Comment: @cde How do you know that? Are you sitting next to the mods to know their actions? Clearly several people found fault with your actions. It seems that the questions you voted to close were reviewed and all found to be perfectly fine.

Comment: @Catija because multiple high rep users found issues with multiple of those questions, while the mod voted to leave open every question in the review queue, as shown in the review history, and the chat history, as shown by the screenshot another user posted.

Comment: @cde if they were off-topic like you said I'm sure they would end up back in the queue even if a mod voted to leave open. The problem is you flagged/voted to close them really fast and with what the community viewed as questionable motives and you fought them on every turn instead of working with them. Just like you are doing now...

Comment: @dom Work with them how? Just agree a bunch of bad questions are good and should stay open, even when others clearly see they are bad?

Comment: @cde There are tons of better ways this could be handled then saying "Look I'm right!" when trying to ask why you were warned about an action. If you don't know what you did wrong by now, no one can help you at this point...

Comment: @Dom questioning a mod, in a non-disrepectful manner (no insults, no vandalism), and not continuing the action, should not result in a ban.

Comment: @dom so could you let me know these better ways so I can act on them instead?

Comment: better ways for who? the community or one single user who thinks they are special?

Comment: @cde - I'm sorry that this happened, but I suggested very early on in the chain of events what the best move on your part would be:  >"@cde - **If you refuse to accept the fact that you did something wrong, it will be more likely that you will be disciplined. *You need to own up to your mistakes, apologize, and let it go (and hope that this is enough to get you off the hook)***. –  Wad Cheber Jul 17 at 21:41"